# Gwt accessing Session id in Client side

Tags: gwt2

atm i have a JSP (my Host page) where i set the Session id via scriptlet with the Request Object. I save this Information in an hidden field and read it with the gwt DOM Object. Is there à better way to do this ? Thanks in advance for help.

Kuku

Comment: Question is, why do you need session id in DOM object?

Better way could be to make GWT service, and just ask it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup this is a valid way to get a hold to a session ID. I assume you have written just a part of you web application in GWT and integrate it into something bigger written in some other language. Since your host page is JSP, I assume the non GWT part of your application is also dynamic.

I don't think that the proposed solution using a GWT service call works in this case. Since you can not match the session ID on the server to the incoming AJAX call.

Instead of using a hidden field, you could encode the session ID in the URL and get it from there, see getParameter(...):

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29

But I actually prefer the solution with the hidden filed, because it does not affect the URL. If you encode transient information in the URL you may lose the ability to bookmark it.